# C++ with D3DX9 - Memory size keeps increasing at a rate of 10 MB/sec - Why?

Tags: c++, 3d, directx

I'm working on a 3D engine as school project.
I've installed virtual leak detector to get rid of memory leaks (and it worked, since I'm not getting any of those dumps anymore).
Recently, I accidentally left my app running for 5 minutes...
And my PC got slow as hell.
I've tracked down the issue by commenting out lines and such, but I can't find out why C++ won't release my cleared memory until I close the application.

PROBLEM:
"Internal" memory leak, looks like C++ is only deleting something once the app closes

CODE:
[My render code (at pastebin Yz79Ck0b)](http://pastebin.com/Yz79Ck0b)

NOTES:
I know I'm not supposed to create a new Mesh each time, but that shouldn't cause this problem, right?
My IDE is Visual Studio 2008, And I'm using a WIN32 project.
When I take out the texture and model, I have 0 bytes memory growth.

Comment: Replace "looks like C++ is only deleting" by "my code is only deleting". Whatever your program does not release as it goes, the operating system will release when the process (program) ends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Sanjit says, you must use `delete[]` to delete arrays - and as DeadMG says, a RAII container is the best-practice way not to mess up freeing your resource.

However, although it's not instantly obvious from the docs, apparently all [Direct3d resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205878.aspx) (including the [`IDirect3d9Texture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205909.aspx) that [`D3DXCreateTextureFromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172801.aspx) creates)  inherit from [`IUnknown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680509.aspx) - they're COM objects, in other words.  You need to [`.Release()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682317.aspx) COM objects when you're done using them:

```
for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
  if (m_Texture[i] != NULL)
    m_Texture[i]->Release();//decrement COM refcount to permit releasing the resource
delete[] m_Texture;
delete[] m_Material;
```

You probably want to get in the habit of wrapping that recurring logic into a handy RAII container.  ATL has such a thing built-in, see the MSDN-docs on [`CComPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezzw7k98%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).  Caveat: I've never used it before, but something just like it is a very good idea if you intend to write anything larger than a toy app using COM.

Comment: +1 for pointing that COM objects need to be freed with Release().

Comment: Thanks again guys - I have one last question - I seem to be racking up bytes of memory here and there - is that normal?

Comment: @Pimgd: DirectX is a serious library. It uses a serious amount of memory. It's normal for even light D3D apps to use quite a bit of memory.

Answer (score 2):

m_Material is an array, you need the [] with the delete operator:

```
delete[] m_Material;
```

Also, looks like m_Texture is an array of pointers which are newed.
D3DXCreateTextureFromFileA(m_Device, d3dxMaterials[i].pTextureFilename, &m_Texture[i])

The proper way of deleting an array of dynamically allocated pointers is:

```
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
      // first delete memory for each index
      if (m_Texture[i] != NULL)
      {
        delete m_Texture[i];
      }
    }

    // then delete the array
    delete[] m_Texture;
```

Comment: You have the same bug with m_Texture.

Comment: The proper way to delete an array of dynamically allocated pointers is with RAII.

Comment: Please don't confuse my post about array cleanup with the RAII design pattern.

Comment: @Sanjit: I'm not. That's the problem.

Comment: @DeadMG: Sanjit is right, `new[]` needs to be paired with `delete[]`.  Wrapping that in an RAII class would be even better, and replacing manual memory management with `std::vector` better yet, but none of that invalidates Sanjit's point.

Comment: @DeadMG: the diagnosis is correct. RAII is one possible solution, but it's not the only valid one.

Comment: Your post has a reasonable chance of being correct, but you can't generally just go about deleting memory allocated with custom functions - you need to use the appropriate deletion function.  Unfortunately, the API doesn't specify which that would be - *blech* (this is a recurring MSDN problem - API docs commonly are missing basic, necessary info).  Since textures are allocated potentially in video memory, it's really quite possible you do indeed need a different deletion function.  I don't know.

Comment: The right way to clear the pointers was the use of delete[] and m_Texture[i]->Release(); (and not delete m_Texture[i] ). Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use RAII to handle any resource that needs freeing, and NOT free them manually.

```
template<typename T> class self_release_ptr {
    T* ptr;
public:
    self_release_ptr(T* newptr) : ptr(newptr) {}
    self_release_ptr() : ptr(0) {}
    ~self_release_ptr() { if (ptr) ptr->Release(); }
    // etc
};
std::vector<self_release_ptr<texture_type>> m_Texture;
```

I could be more specific, but would need to see the definition of the classes.

Comment: The RAII container you define leaves dangerous bits to `// etc` - either refer to an existing one, or complete it (with assignment&copy constructors); this one's liable to blow up in peoples faces.

Comment: @Eamon: I'm not going to go writing an entire smart pointer for him. It's my job to give him the idea, not implement it.

Comment: I understand, but it's _really easy_ to screw up smart pointer implementations if you don't quite understand the details of the C++ RAII model - leaving the nasty bits to `// etc` is asking him to shoot himself in the foot.  If you don't want to implement it - don't! He should either use an existing smart pointer, or a complete example.  If you remove your code sample or better yet list the various ingredients required your answer can't be misunderstood.  (To be clear: I downvoted because I've made such an error in the past).